# What is meant by "show the following relations over $A$" in this problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logarithms

### **Will someone explain what is being asked for by "show the following relations over $A$"?**

**Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$**

**Show the following relations over $A$.**

**1.** $R1 = \{(x, y) \mid \log2 x < \log2 y \}$

**2.** $R2 = \{(x, y) \mid \log2 x = 2 + \log2 y \}$

**3.** $R3 = \{(x, y) \mid \log2 x = \log2 y \}$

**4.** $R4 = \{(x, y) \mid 3 = \log2 x + \log2 y \}$

---

**Part II**

**Will someone help me understand what is meant by the following:**

For each of the above relations, indicate whether it is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric and/or transitive.

Comment: I'm guessing that they want you define the sets $R_i$ such that the condition on the right holds (so for which $x$ and $y$ the condition holds).

Comment: So I plug in the values from set $A$ into the inequality conditions on the right for each set $R$, and list, for each set $R$, which values from set $A$ satisfied the inequality?

Comment: That is my guess, yes.

Comment: What about part II of the question?  We haven't covered any of this in class yet.  I'm just trying to get a general understanding of next week's homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a worked example of what I think is being asked for.  Suppose

$$R5 = \left\{(x,y) \mid \frac{10}{x^2} < \frac{y}{3}\right\}$$

The set of tuples that satisfy this relation is
$$\left\{
(3, 6),
(4, 3),
(4, 4),
(4, 5),
(4, 6),
(5, 3),
(5, 4),
(5, 5),
(5, 6),
(6, 3),
(6, 4),
(6, 5),
(6, 6)\right\}$$
.

A relation is reflexive iff $\forall x \in A. R(x,x)$. This **fails** for R5 because we do not have, for example, $R5(1,1)$.

A relation is symmetric iff $\forall x,y \in A. R(x,y) \leftrightarrow R(y,x)$. This **fails** for R5 because we have $R5(4,3)$ but not $R5(3,4)$.

A relation is antsymmetric iff $\forall x,y \in A. R(x,y) \leftrightarrow \neg R(y,x)$. This **fails** for R5 because we have both $R5(3,6)$ and $R5(6,3)$.

A relation is transitive iff $\forall x,y,z \in A. R(x,y) \wedge R(y,z) \rightarrow R(x,z)$.  This **holds** for R5.